# KnockOutJS Inserting Data in a Nested Array

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to insert data to a nested array. The structure of the JSON object is like this:

```
Data: {
    MembershipName:
    Countries: {
                CountryName: "USA"
                States:
                                {
                                  State: "Alabama"
                                       {
                                          Members: {}
                                       } 
                                }
       }
}
```

I tried using the push function below, it's being added when I debug it in the console but my View isn't updating.

```
self.Data()[0]["Countries"].push(
            {
            "CountryName": 'Success!'
            }
        );
```

I would like to add to the Countries array specifically for this specific index (I used index for 0). Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Ricalyn, not really sure what this has to do knockoutjs.  Could you please add some more detail and enough code to help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @NathanFisher updated. The self.push is the KnockOutJS related. I'm trying to push to a nested array.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure is not so clear, it seems that Data is an object (but you go through it with [0]) and countries is another object (but you want to push a new value like an array).

Maybe you thought about this data structure:

```
Data: {
    MembershipName: {},
    Countries: [
        {
            CountryName: "USA",
            States: [
                { 
                    State: "Alabama",
                    Members: []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In this case, you can push the new country with:

```
self.Data().Countries.push({ /* new country data */ });
```

Comment: Arrays should be observableArray, is that it?

Comment: Hi @Bludev yes, I actually have some issues with my mapping, but I solved it as well, it was the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this by doing the following:

```
self.Data()[index].Countries.push(
            new countriesModel(
                {
                    'CountryName': selectedCountry()
                }
            )
        );
```